# Submodule custom attributes AndroidStudio has lint problem

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

when I declare my `attrs` at submodule like this:

```
<attr name="radius" format="dimension" />
<attr name="border" format="dimension" />
<attr name="border_color" format="reference|color" />

<declare-styleable name="RoundImageView">
    <attr name="radius" />
    <attr name="border" />
    <attr name="border_color" />
</declare-styleable>

<declare-styleable name="CircleImageView">
    <attr name="border" />
    <attr name="border_color" />
</declare-styleable>
```

but when I use in my app, attr cannot automatically prompt:

[image]

by the way this works well when i run app. just has lint notice and attributes not prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem probably because of attribute name clashing. Try changing your attribute to something like this:

```
<attr name="radius" format="dimension" />
<attr name="border" format="dimension" />
<attr name="border_color" format="reference|color" />

<declare-styleable name="RoundImageView">
    <attr name="riv_radius" />
    <attr name="riv_border" />
    <attr name="riv_border_color" />
</declare-styleable>

<declare-styleable name="CircleImageView">
    <attr name="civ_border" />
    <attr name="civ_border_color" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Then use the View attribute by its View type.

Comment: thanks. as you see i want RoundImageView and  CircleImageView use two same attributes 'border' and 'border_color'. what should i do then.

Answer (score 0):

I have two way to fix namespace prefix problem.

1. add ignore code in xml. `tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"`
2. uncheck `Preferences -> Edit -> Inspection -> Missing Android XML namespace`.

But attributes still not prompt.